# Custom Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm

I'm complety new to this but I finally got around to building a Linux kernel so far so good. I am following a guide here:

[A10-OLinuXino-LIME](http://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/A10-OLinuXino-LIME#A10-OLinuXino-LIME-CopyKernelFiles)

My problem/concern is now I am in a .config menu and I've been searching online to no avail to determine what does it mean by a  modularizes features verse  includes, like should I switch to  if I want those features to be there?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated it! I'm primarily doing this to include WiFi usb drivers I will be needing.

Comment: Did you `make menuconfig` when building the kernel?

Comment: I don't think so I did `./build_kernel.sh` which I believe ran that since that's where I am in the menuconfig (I googled to confirm the image was the same).

Comment: So correction yes I did do that when building the kernel - so should I just leave stuff I want included as <M> or <Y> ?

Comment: `M` is for modules (dynamically loaded), `Y` is for hard kernel part (statically linked).

Comment: Thanks figured it out and my install is working just fine! (I don't know why the down vote...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what system you run this kernel. If it's an embedded system, then you will probably be more concerned about memory benefits. In RAM you can win about several Kbytes per module. For the devices are not represented in the system/hardware, it then has a sense to  put some drivers on Modules. Some modules can be taking more time when the kernel starts, and it is probably better to load them later, when the system is running.

You will probably be concerned about disk space, if you put some stuff Compiled-in so you can have a benefit because you don't need to have a module loading utility.

Have a look at [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/benefit-of-kernel-module-compiled-inside-kernel) as well

Answer (score 1):

> I'm primarily doing this to include WiFi usb drivers I will be needing.

Its not necessary to build the complete kernel unless to build a USB WiFi driver. All you need is the kernel headers installed. From `make menuconfig` select the module you want to build, choose `M`, save the .config. This will build a module which can be loaded, instead of getting compiled as a part of the vmlinux image.